# How many v_tables there are for a class that inherites twice

Tags: c++

```
struct A 
{
    virtual void f1() {}
};

struct B: public A {};

struct C: public A {};

struct D: public B,public C {};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(A)<<" "<<sizeof(B)<<" "<<sizeof(C)<<" "<<sizeof(D)<<endl;
    cout<<"_______"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

1. The output in my system (c9.o): `8 8 8 16`
   Does it mean that D have 2 virtual pointers to 2 virtual tables? If yes, where 
   is the pointers location?
2. In case we remove the fucntion `f1` from `struct A`, the output is: `1 8 8 16`. Same question goes here also.
3. In case we doesn't remove `f1` and now `B` and `C` inherit virtual from `A`, the output is: `8 8 8 16`. Same question goes here also.

Comment: Do note that this is implementation defined.  A cleaver enough compiler can remove the vtable if it knows at compile time what the run time type will be.

Comment: @NathanOliver Changing the layout of an object is almost never possible.

Comment: `D` owns 2 `A` which must have 2 different addresses.

Comment: @Jarod42 Does both v_pointers located at struct `A` ? In case `B` and `C` inheritce with virtual from `A`, Does `D` have 2 v_pointers also?

Comment: @Jarod42 D doesn't *own* A. It's an `is-a` relationship, not a `has-a`.

Comment: There shouldn't be any vtables for a class which doesn't have any virtual methods.

Comment: You should be aware that the ISO C++ standard has exactly *zero* mentions of the word `vtable` or `v-table`. In other words it's *one* way to do an implementation. Hence, you should be mentioning *which* implementation you're interested in.